# Можно ли делать проверку через new DirectoryInfo(Path).Exists?

Tags: c#, инспекция-кода

Можно ли использовать данный метод для проверки существования папки?

```
public static DirectoryInfo DirEx(string Path)
{
      return new DirectoryInfo(Path); 
}

public static readonly string des = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.DesktopDirectory) + "\\Folder";

bool FolderDesk = DirEx(des).Exists;
if (!FolderDesk)
{
     Console.WriteLine("Папка не существует");
}
else
 Console.WriteLine("Папка существует");
```

Или же использовать старый добрый:

```
Directory.Exists(path);
```

?

или же использовать такую конструкцию:

```
bool FolderDesk = Directory.Exists(des);
if (!FolderDesk)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Как-то так?");
}
```

Comment: По большому счету длать можно что угодно и как взбредет в голову, но зачем все усложнять, если есть более простой и компактный способ?

Comment: @sp7, Просто использовать `if (Directory.Exists(Path)){}` ?

Comment: Имхо, короткий вариант нормально читается, так зачем его раздувать. Причем если в `if` всего одно условие, то и заводить доп. переменную я бы не стал

Comment: @ArteS да, используйте его.

Comment: @Андрей, Значит 1-ым способом можно воспользоваться если в `if` есть более условий?    `var di = new DirectoryInfo(path); if(di.Exists) { }`, я просто где-то вычитал что лучше использовать `DirectoryInfo`, просто какой вариант отработает  лучше?!

Comment: @ArteS что значит лучше? Запомните простое правило, код должен быть настолько простым и понятным, насколько это возможно. А лишнее нагромождение кода этому не способствует.

Comment: @sp7, понятно, я просто думал сделать по красоте :D

Comment: @ArteS, но чем короче код - тем он красивее, не так ли?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Самый удобный способ как по мне, это записать значение "Directory.Exists" в переменную.
К примеру

```
bool name = Directory.Exists(path);
```

И в последствии обращаться к переменной "name"

Comment: Изначально думал так сделать, остановился на таком способе.